# CSS Bug: moderator flag color set the same as the background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Hi, I think I discovered my first (minor) bug — the moderator flag circle no longer shows the number of pending edits. The offending CSS looks to be:

```
.mod-flag-indicator {
  color: #C6751F;
}
```

Comment: The fix will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the color to white, the change will go live tonight.